# Как рассчитать координаты объекта наблюдаемого с дрона?

Tags: c++, opencv, геометрия

Столкнулся с задачей и не понимаю алгоритм действий...

С дрона я обнаруживаю объекты на местности и получаю их изображение высчитываю координаты x,y в пикселях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например я знаю что разрешение картинки с камеры 1920х1080 и искомый объект находится в центре картинки, и его координата условно в центре x=(1920/2); y=(1080/2)

Я знаю gps координаты дрона на момент обнаружения например (55.411714, 37.890895), его высоту (5 метров), угол камеры например 30 градусов. перепады ландшафта нивелируются.

Как мне получить GPS координаты обнаруженного объекта?

Comment: Никак, для этого нужно еще знать расстояние от дрона до объекта. "gps координаты" - рука лицо

Comment: В общем случае - простая геометрия. На таких масштабах, пренебрегаем формой Земли. Вид сверху, по направлению высчитываете луч куда смотрит дрон. Расстояние от дрона - Прямоугольный треугольник, вид сбоку. Знаете точку у прямого угла (ваши GPS). Высота вертикального катета 5м. Угол 30гр. Находите точку второго катета. Длина второго катета - расстояние по лучу на виде сверху.

Comment: @user7860670 вы не правы. Дрон в пространстве известен, луч взгляда тоже (наклон, объект обещан в центре). Земля допущена плоская. Этого вполне достаточно. Сложности будут только если величины большие и дело у полюсов ..

Comment: Уточните, вам же известен и наклон и направление взгляда дрона - два угла?

Comment: @Kromster для простоты можно считать что дрон смотрит прямо на объект. можно учитывать только то, что угол камеры отклонен от оси на 30гр вниз.

Comment: @Kromster логику примерно осознаю, но все равно не понимаю как 3д координаты рассчитать

Comment: По приведенным данным можно только определить окружность, на которой находится объект.

Comment: @Mbo а какие данные еще нужны? какой алгоритм должен быть?

Comment: @Kromster Вы походу другую задачу стали решать - пересечение луча взгляда с плоской землей.

Comment: Например, азимут

Comment: У меня нет понимания как считать 3д координаты в данном кейсе. Если можно какие-то примеры... буду благодарен

Comment: @user7860670 *"пересечение луча взгляда с плоской землей"* - ну да, и в этой точке (по центру картинки) и находится требуемый объект ТС.

Comment: Снова вас спрашиваю, т.к. ответа вы не дали - вам известен и наклон и направление взгляда дрона - два угла? Или у вас только наклон вниз, а Азимута (на север) нету?

Comment: @Kromster да, только вниз угол есть...я пока не рассматривал добавление азимута в формулу. Пока хочу понять как без отклонений азимута искать, хотя дальше и его нужно будет добавить

Comment: Без азимута - никак. Можете только принять что если дрон невысоко и смотрит боле-менее вниз, то положение объекта совпадает с положением дрона. Подумай сам - вот ты дрон, твое GPS известно, у тебя глаза на высоте 1,6м, ты смотришь на ботинки на полу - где они расположены, если ты не знаешь смотришь ты на север или на юг?

Comment: @Kromster хорошо, нужен азимут. какой формулой нужно руководствоватьсяв целом для рассчета координат?

Comment: Если у вас азимута нет - уже сказали - "положение объекта = положение дрона", т.к. точнее сказать нельзя. Если азимут есть - алгоритм во 2м комментарии.